# Bind touch event to elements created by array

Tags: android, jquery

How to make touch event work on single element of each created by this function. This code doesn't work since it makes all of the '#demo-1 p' background-color change together even I touch one of them.

```
function token1(r) {
    for (var j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
        if (r[j].match(srr[0], "g")) {
            $('<p>').html(r[j]).appendTo("#demo-1");
            scnt++;     
            $('#demo-1 p').bind("touchstart", function (event) {
                $('#demo-1 p').css('background-color', 'red')
            });
            $('#demo-1 p').bind("touchmove", function (event) {
                $('#demo-1 p').css('background-color', 'white')
            });
            $('#demo-1 p').bind("touchend", function (event) {
                $('#demo-1 p').css('background-color', 'white')
            });
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the `jQuery.on()`?
It's really easy to use:

```
$( '#demo' ).on('touchstart', 'p', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
...
```

**Note**: *This should only be executed once. So put it outside the for loop (before or after).*

Comment: haven't found that jQuery.on() could solve this. But it seems the code is much shorter, should be better in mobile environment. I have to try this, thank man :)

Comment: It's the combination of `jQuery.on()` and `$(this)` that will solve your problem because `$(this)` refers to the `<p>` element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it by targetting the child element of it

```
$("#demo-1").bind("touchstart", function(e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.is("p")) {
                $target.css('background-color', 'red')
            }
        });
```